# I want to use the strategy of wordpress for url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess

What is the strategy of wordpress for url rewriting.
In .htaccess they have only few line of code,for my app I need more than 80 line of code...
To 20 app's apache blows up and server too.

I have url structure like this:

```
http://localhost/list.php?title=two-wheel; (title var is used for search)
http://localhost/list.php?title=four-wheel&category=cars;
http://localhost/list.php?title=four-wheel&category=cars?features=car-alarm;
http://localhost/list.php?title=four-wheel&region=wyoming&category=cars?features=car-alarm;
```

and manny other pages.

How could I write my url's like them?
Can you provide an example of what code is need to write in .php page and in .htaccess based by wordpress strategy?

Comment: I don't really understand what this has to do with Wordpress, can you elaborate?

Comment: It has nothing to do with wordpress just need to understand how they do that.And to shrink my htaccess not to make so manny requests

Comment: maybe edit accordingly? I think the Wordpress reference is more confusing than  helpful

Comment: +1 @hakre -- you need to look in to using regex (or regular expressions) to match patterns in your URI strings for re-writing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress loads any request into the application and then loads a map of regular expressions stored inside the database to resolve the actual command of the request.

This is done to support other types of URL rewriters - not only .htaccess but also PATHINFO and error pages.

Next to that plugins can add their own "rewrite-rules".

However this also has it's cons as it can consume a lot of resources and bring the script down.

If you want to rewrite URLs like them, feel free to use the sourcecode publicly available. However, I would suggest to review your rewrite rules first. Only because there are not so many rules within the .htaccess file, this does not mean that are no rules at all.

Comment: I think I understand what Morowind is asking - i.e. Wordpress can handle a lot of rewrites/redirects; how do they achieve this? The above answer seems to answer this question. There is also a related post about managing memory for a large number of rewrites here - http://serverfault.com/questions/113906/is-there-a-limit-for-htaccess , and a bit more of an explanation about what the Wordpress .htaccess rules actually do - http://davidwalsh.name/wordpress-htaccess-file-is-genius